# Is it possible to run a for loop to plot graphs and produce a table of contents at the top which shows the location of each at the top?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, matplotlib

I'm working on project where I have to create plots for multiple states. I know I can use subplots but they are not producing visually pleasing results so I would rather keep them printed one after the other.

At the end of the for loop, whenever I need to find info I have to scroll around trying to find certain states. Is it possible to have the locations printed at the top so I can quickly jump to the graph?

I have provided my code as it is now.

```
the08legend = [] '$'

print(the08legend)'$'



for state in state_df['State'].unique():'$'

the08legend.append(state)
plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
my_range =range(1,len(state_df[state_df['State']==state].index)+1)

st_df = state_df[state_df['State'] == state]
st_df = st_df.sort_values('rep08vot_perc')

plt.axvline(x=50, c='green', alpha = 0.2)
plt.hlines(y=my_range, xmin=st_df['rep08vot_perc'], xmax=st_df['dem08vot_perc'], color='ghostwhite', alpha=1)
plt.scatter(y = my_range, x = st_df['rep08vot_perc'], c = 'red', label='Republican vote share')
plt.scatter(y = my_range, x = st_df['dem08vot_perc'], c = 'blue', label = 'Democrat vote share')
plt.xlim(0,100)
plt.title(f'The vote shares in {state} 2008 election')
plt.ylabel(f'The county in {state} where vote was counted')
plt.xlabel('Percentage share of votes')
plt.legend(loc = 1)
plt.show()
```

I know what I did is obviously not going to print the resulting list, however, is it possible to make that happen?